# SignatureDoesNotMatch Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying upload a file to Google Cloud Storage, so I created a signed url and trying to Upload but this works only in cURL on Linux Bash, in web browser (Chrome) or in Postman I get the following error:

[Postman Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bldxy.png)

The same error appears on Google Chrome Browser.
I am using Content Type "multipart/form-data" in Signed Upload Url creation and on headers of Postman.

In Linux Bash works fine with command **curl -H "Content-Type: image/png" -XPUT --upload-file 39470cc8-0a9d-11e8-9e10-90e6bacc184f https://storage.googleapis.com/{bucket-name}/39470cc8-0a9d-11e8-9e10-90e6bacc184f?GoogleAccessId={accessId}&Expires=1517854902&Signature=LaAaOVEk3XLEYpQSl6fEuJ%2BmR5OfSMSKyWZP9MrRNMmQxPv0Ed0c6SzVhAoTU8fBcVABJsAQ5%2BmkjYVMGVpdyaNu8Ecub3D0cfEVtU982Q0ues23GHlxCoWO6gaMyqLQCRulHJ6ciH8tr3m5wP0cDnOIAxiAVicvFbjAZCb4P5rIXnD1ypte4xVoOED5h%2F3kmRVetyT9c4j6q7e4hm0UnUIjcD3trTDRGubFWc6%2FFAAdh6DDCnKC%2BdeKhO5hOojfTklPFeOstdMm8wtBGYS78giGhODs0lfZdUgn%2FmTxw6jTcnjo9WAnsq5gPcF9qa80i7u7WYKxOAykBaiPr6T%2FeQ%3D%3D&response-content-type=image%2Fpng**

Thanks!

Comment: You should keep your ID's etc safe and insert placeholder data values only.

Comment: Thanks @Terrance00, I'll corrected this information in the post.

Comment: No worries - it's for your own protection I suppose (good habits and all), good luck with the issue.

Some other advice - have a look at the docs or look for any code examples/tutorials - usually your best bet to get around this sort of stuff.